# Problem with rendering a React component in another component for SPFX

Tags: spfx, sharepoint-framework, react, reactjs

This is my first post here, I guess :)

I am writing because I have a task to make a Shopping app which should be made in SharePoint Framework and use React as a framework.

My current problem is that, I have two components, one in a file called **ShoppingWebpart.tsx** (which should render other components) and an inner component in the file **Cart.tsx** which I want to render in **ShoppingWebpart.tsx**.

The problem is I get an error in **ShoppingWebpart.tsx** when trying to render the content in **Cart.tsx**. The error is:

[image]

Here I will attach the code:

**Cart.tsx**:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import styles from './ShoppingWebpart.module.scss';
import { IShoppingWebpartProps, ISPList, ISPLists } from './IShoppingWebpartProps';
import { escape } from '@microsoft/sp-lodash-subset';

export interface IShoppingWebpartState{
  items: ISPLists[];
}

export default class Cart extends React.Component<IShoppingWebpartProps, any> {
  constructor(props: IShoppingWebpartProps){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      items: this.props.list
    }
  }

  public render(): React.ReactElement<IShoppingWebpartProps> {
    console.log("Render: ", this.state.items);
    let products = [];

    return (
      <div className={ styles.shoppingWebpart }>
        <div className={ styles.container }>

          <div className={ styles.row }>
            <div className={ styles.column }>
              <span>Cart details should go here</span>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

module.exports = Cart;
```

**ShoppingWebpart.tsx**:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import styles from './ShoppingWebpart.module.scss';
import { IShoppingWebpartProps, ISPList, ISPLists } from './IShoppingWebpartProps';
import { escape } from '@microsoft/sp-lodash-subset';
var Cart = require('./Cart.tsx');

export interface IShoppingWebpartState{
  items: ISPLists[];
}

export default class ShoppingWebpart extends React.Component<IShoppingWebpartProps, any> {
  constructor(props: IShoppingWebpartProps){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      items: this.props.list
    }
  }

  public render(): React.ReactElement<IShoppingWebpartProps> {
    console.log("Render: ", this.state.items);
    let products = [];

    for(let i = 0; i < this.state.items.length; i++){
      products.push(<div key={this.state.items[i].Id} className={styles.productItem}>
        {this.state.items[i].Product} <br/>
        {this.state.items[i].Category} <br/>
        {this.state.items[i].ProductDescription} <br/>
        {this.state.items[i].Price}<br/>
        <button>Add to Cart</button>
      </div>)
    }

    return (
      <div className={ styles.shoppingWebpart }>
        <div className={ styles.container }>

          <div className={ styles.row }>
            <span className={ styles.title }>Welcome to Kevins webshop</span>
            <p className={ styles.subTitle }>Produkter till enastående priser.</p>

            <Cart></Cart>

            <div className={ styles.productItem }>
              {products}
            </div> 
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the file structure:

[image]

All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, you are mixing up the Node "require" with a module export and a default export for the class "Cart".

**You should try the following:**

- Remove the module export from **Cart.tsx** (last line)
- Replace `var Cart = require('./Cart.tsx');` in **ShoppingWebPart.tsx** with `import Cart from './Cart';`
- Provide the required props to the Cart element in the `render` function of **ShoppingWebPart.tsx**

  `<Cart items={ this.state.items } />`

Comment: Thanks a lot Anon, but now I get another error. It says: Module '"../../../../../../../../........../src/webparts/shoppingWebpart/components/Cart"' has no exported member 'Cart'.  on `import { Cart } from './Cart';` in ShoppingWebpart.tsx. Please forgive me for asking to much, I am a beginner when it comes to React. Thanks

Comment: I assume that the Cart.tsx is actually in the same folder as ShoppingWebPart.tsx? If not, can you share a partial screenshot of the folder structure?

How did you create the project - using the yeoman generator?

Comment: Yes, Cart.tsx and ShoppingWebPart.tsx are in the same folder and yes, I did use yeoman generator. Then ShoppingWebPart.tsx is created automatically after typing yo @microsoft/sharepoint but Cart.tsx I created myself in the same folder as ShoppingWebPart.tsx.

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot of the files that the folder contains? I guess there is no additional file called Cart.ts? Try explicitely stating `import { Cart } from './Cart.tsx';` if such a file exists.

Comment: I now added a screenshot of my filestructure to my original post. Hope its clear and ShoppingWebPart.tsx and Cart.tsx are in the components folder. When I write `import { Cart } from './Cart.tsx';` then I get following error: **An import path cannot end with a '.tsx' extension. Consider importing './Cart' instead.**

Comment: Ok, I see. Two alternatives should finally fix that: 1. Change the import to `import Cart from "./Cart";` (i.e. without the curly brackets) or 2. Revert the import to `import { Cart } from './Cart';` and remove the `default` keyword from the Cart class.

Comment: When I try the two alternatives, both alternatives gives me the following error: **Type '{ items: any; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<Cart> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }> & Readonly<IShoppingWebpartProps>'.
  Property 'items' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<Cart> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }> & Readonly<IShoppingWebpartProps>'.** 

Error is on `<Cart items={ this.state.items }></Cart>` row in ShoppingWebpart.tsx file.

Comment: That's because you are using the same `IShoppingWebpartProps` interface for the props of your Cart class. You will need to have a look at what objects you need to pass to your cart (probably only the items that it contains) and define another interface for that accordingly. There are quite some good tutorials for React + TypeScript (with JSX) out there, e.g. have a look at the last example on [this page](https://charleslbryant.gitbooks.io/hello-react-and-typescript/content/TypeScriptAndReact.html).